# Marketing Cloud Connector - what happens when Salesforce Integration is disconnected?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am looking at reconfiguring our Marketing Cloud connector. The reason is that I want to use dedicated users (on the Salesforce and MC side) for the connector to improve our ability to track changes made by the connector vs other integrations.

Right now we use the connector for the following:

- Synchronising data into Marketing Cloud from Salesforce
- Journeys that use Salesforce Data Event as an entry event
- Journeys that update Salesforce data as part of the journey
- Salesforce Reports as the import source for data extensions (using automations)
- Sending tracking data for email sends back to Salesforce

I have tested all aspects of this change except for one: in MC, Administration > Account > Salesforce Integration. If you click "edit" a blue "Disconnect Account" button becomes available. I would need to disconnect and then reconnect with the appropriate Salesforce user credentials.

What I am struggling to find info on and to understand is what happens when I click the blue button, disconnect, and then immediately reconnect with the new user credentials? What does this impact?

For example, with the data synchronisation from Salesforce to MC, will it require all the field mappings to be redone?

The other major concern is around the journeys. We currently have a New Subscriber journey running with 1000s of contacts in it. A contact can be in the journey for up to 10 weeks depending on the path it takes. Will these journeys be impacted?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It will impact more or less everything that relies on Sales Cloud data, so all the points you listed will be affected plus some additional functions like Tracking Data, cross-cloud AMPScript and so on.

There is a short documentation article available on [**Disconnecting the Clouds**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_disconnect_account.htm&type=5) and what happens when you do so.

In short, yes, you will need to configure your Synchronised Data Extensions again and map the fields.

Journeys will be impacted if they are either based on Salesforce Entry Data, have Sales Cloud events or you have some Split Decisions configured using the Sales Cloud Data, or your Emails/SMS use cross-cloud AMPscript.

Though as mentioned before, the tracking activity will be stopped entirely for the downtime and there is no way to get the 'lost' IER's later created in Sales Cloud.

Comment: Thanks @Rain. I missed that article. With regards to journeys that fit the criteria you describe above, how are they impacted? Will all the contacts get kicked out?